# How many hot electrons are in solar cells that do not thermalize?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons, semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

When an electron in a solar cell is excited beyond the conduction band edge, it will most likely thermalize which can only be counted as a heat loss. But in a few cases the electron will directly recombine back to the valence band, correct? My question: How "often" does this happen?

I heard of the future technology Hot-carrier solar cells (HCSC). They aim at using all of these thermalization energy, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about recombination dynamics in semiconductors. This is a vast topic!

But let's make some assumptions:

- A lot of hot-carrier research has be done in the III-V semiconductor family. So let's restrict ourselves to GaAs.
- Undoped semiconductor
- Let's assume our material quality is so good that we can ignore recombination via defects.
- Let's restrict ourselves to talk about the recombination dynamics of electrons rather than holes.

Given these assumption, what are the remaining interband processes cause an electron in the conduction band to recombine with a hole in the valence band?

1. Radiative recombination

   Radiative recombination is proportional to the concentration of electrons $n$ and holes $p$.

$$
R_{rad} = B n p
$$

2. Auger recombination

   Auger recombination of electrons is a three particle process. An electron in the conduction band will recombine with a hole in the valence band and transfer the energy to a second hole (the third particle in the process).

$$
R_{Auger} = C_{p} n p^2
$$

To illustrate the point radiative recombination is the top process and Auger recombination is the bottom in the diagram.

[image: radiative and Auger recombination]

**Aside:** Auger recombination (and it's inverse mechanism impact ionisation) is interesting from a hot-carrier solar cell perspective because it keeps energy within the electronic system. Moreover, Auger recombination reduces electron density in exchange for increasing the average energy (i.e. temperature) of the hole distribution.

Let's write the recombination rate as the sum of these processes,

$$
R = B n p + C_{p} n p^2
$$

[Values for GaAs](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/GaAs/electric.html) are $B=7.2 \times 10^{-10}\text{cm}^3\text{s}^{-1}$ and $C_p=10^{-30}\text{cm}^6\text{s}^{-1}$

Now, if you can estimate the electron and hole density you can calculate the recombination rate.

Let's assume that $n=p$ because the semiconductor is undoped, the recombination rates of the radiative (blue) and Auger (purple) are shown in the plot,

[image: recombination rate]

The recombination rate is very much dependent on the carrier density generated in the device.

This is a simplification of a very complicated problem. There are a number of additional details not considered

1. Here we consider the ensemble rate. A better approach would be to consider the rate of carriers at different parts in k-space.
2. We are using coefficients for derived from experiment at room temperature. Probably they will have some temperature dependence or at least have been pushed beyond their limit of applicability.

Comment: Why should a carrier recombine if it is in equilibrium with the surrounding lattice?

Comment: There are different types of equilibrium and equilibrium between different systems. That’s a good questions to ask. There is not enough room here, so will update the answer.

Comment: I wish I could book you for a voice chat where things probably would be much easier to explain, because you seem like a real expert, haha. :D I am not a physics student, but teacher for physics (and special education, so physics is limited in my curriculum). Perhaps this limits my knowledge. I hope my questions are not too confusing. But I don't find answers in textbooks or papers. For example, a good explanation on the Urbach tail...
And I am still wondering, how many hot electrons in non-hot carrier solar cells directly recombine to the valence band... :/

Comment: Happy to help. You have not accepted any of the answers to any of the questions I’ve helped you with. I can update this answer with some more information a bit later

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd give other people chances to answer, since you are the only one who answered them so far. With this, I feel like you answered the second one about the HCSC, but not the first, with respect to hot-carriers in "normal" solar cells. There is also a lot I don't understand about the answer, for example why the CB and VB look inverted in the figure. If it makes you happy I can of course accept all of your answers.

Comment: Yeah. There are some specific improvements I can make, you are right. No, it was just a general comment. When I first joined this site I left question unaccepted because I didn’t know they had to be accepted if good! Do what you want, it’s fine.

Comment: Ah, I confused "accept answer" with "best answer" which you have on other platforms. Of course I "accept" your answers, that is the least I can say about your helpfulness! :-)

Comment: I updated this to be a more useful answer!

Comment: Thanks, interesting! But it seems to me that this is not the answer to my question: You answered, in general, how many (different) recombination processes there are. But I am only interested in those, where the recombination sets free photons with an energy above the band gap. (Is that correct to say, as if solar cells are LEDs, only with non-visible light? Doesn't each recombination process involve a photon or heat only ?)

Comment: OK. I had a go. You should probably unmark this as unaccepted then and see if someone else answers. It’s not exactly clear what you are asking. If you can update the questions with those criteria and a diagram of the transition type you are seeking maybe someone else may help.

Comment: I mean that some hot electrons thermalize to the edge of the CB before they recombine to the VB, and some directly recombine to the edge of the VB. And I just want to know how many do the first and how many do the latter. :/